# Iterating through QTreeWidget Items

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I use a `QTreeWidget` in my project which is a list of tests that I want to run.

For example, **Test 1**, **Test 2**, **Test 3**, **Test 4** etc.

**Test 2** and **Test 4** have children **Test A**, **Test B**, **Test C** etc.

Once **Test 1** is done, I want **Test A** of **Test 2** to be highlighted in the tree and display the correct form in my `QVBoxLayout` on the UI. Once **Test A** is finished running, I want **Test 2** of **Test B** to be highlighted in the tree and showing the form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMnjA.png)

I have tried the following:

In the `.h` file, I have:

```
QHash<int, QWidget*> treeFormHash;
```

The constructor in the `.cpp` file has this:

```
treeFormHash.insert(0,  Test1FormObj);
treeFormHash.insert(1,  Test2AFormObj);
treeFormHash.insert(2,  Test2BFormObj);
treeFormHash.insert(3,  Test3FormObj);
treeFormHash.insert(4,  Test4AFormObj);
treeFormHash.insert(5,  Test4BFormObj);
```

In the `.cpp` file:

```
void on_Next_btn_clicked() 
{ 
     QHashIterator<int, QWidget*> i(treeFormHash);

     QModelIndex currentTestStep = ui->treeWidget->currentIndex();

     int y = currentTestStep.row() + 1;

     currentTestStep = currentTestStep.siblingAtRow(y);

     QTreeWidgetItem *item = ui->treeWidget->currentItem();

     if(ui->treeWidget->itemBelow(item)->childCount() == 0)
     {
       ui->treeWidget->setCurrentItem(ui->treeWidget->itemBelow(item) , 0);
     }
     else
     {
       currentTestStep = currentTestStep.siblingAtRow(y+1);
       item = ui->treeWidget->currentItem();
       ui->treeWidget->setCurrentItem(ui->treeWidget->itemBelow(item) , 0);        
     }

     while(i.hasNext()) //Returns true if there is at least one item ahead of the iterator//
     {
        i.next();

        if(i.key() == y)
        {
           ui->verticalLayout->itemAt(0)->widget()->setVisible(false);
           ui->verticalLayout->insertWidget(0, i.value());
           break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not realizing that if you need to iterate through a `QTreeWidgetItem` children, you have to consider that they are indexed relatively to their parent, meaning they are indexed **from** `0` **to** `childrenCount()-1`, not **from** `parent->index()+1` **to** `parent->index()+childrenCount()`.

Example:

```
- Test1 0

- Test2 1
     - TestA 0
     - TestB 1
     - TestC 2

 - Test3 2

 - Test4 3
     - TestA 0
     - TestB 1
     - TestC 2
```

Based on this, you can easily modify your code to handle iterating each item's children. And again, be careful to not iterate over `childrenCount()`, and to save the index of the iterated parent.